# Combine 4 rows based on common ID and Date

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a query that returns 4 lines per ID. I would like to be able to merge these into one single row in a new table, based on the ID and Date.

Can anyone help? I've researched and seem can't find any examples.

Simplified version of how the data looks at the moment:

[image: view image]

There's no more fields to identify if it's in or out. This is a log type database usually 4 entries a day per user id.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select t.user_id,t.time_log,substring_index(t.tstring,'#',1) am_in,substring_index(substring_index(t.tstring,'#',2),'#',-1) am_out,
substring_index(substring_index(t.tstring,'#',-2),'#',1) pm_in,substring_index(t.tstring,'#',-1) pm_out 
from
  (select h.user_id,h.time_log,group_concat(h.stime order by h.stime separator '#') tstring
  from user_hardware h
  group by h.user_id,h.time_log
  ) t;
```

But ensure that same `stime` will not occur twice for same `user_id` and `time_log` i.e. `user_id,time_log,stime` should be **unique key**.